# Retrieve deleted package from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, restore

I have deleted a package from my Java code in eclipse and now I need it back. I am not able to find it when I click on "restore from local history". Is there any other way to retrieve it?

Comment: Where did you clicked _Restore from Local History..._? It works only with a right-click on an ancestor container.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

try to move your complete project to different folder, and give a path to new workspace to eclipse and import as maven/gradle (pom)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).